# Spyder closing abruptly

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, spyder, ntdll

**Spyder shuts down abruptly while trying to save/excess folder.**

Using: Windows 10, Anaconda Distribution, Python 3.7.6, Qt 5.9.6,PyQt5 5.9.2

I have searched through the Internet & tried re-installing Anaconda, re-setting Spyder etc.
But nothing I have done so far has solved the problem.

*The windows event viewer shows the following error log.**Looks like ntdll is interfering*

Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.6150.1013, time stamp: 0x5e163a94
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.18362.815, time stamp: 0xb29ecf52
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f9229
Faulting process id: 0x20b0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d61ec5f5b4fa53
Faulting application path: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

**Has anybody had a similar problem? Is there anyway I can fix this problem?**

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "trying to save/excess folder"?

Comment: I write some code & try to save it/ try to open an existing python code file- it results in spyder to suddenly close.

Comment: Please see [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3903). That's the only issue we know that can cause the problem you mentioned.

Comment: The solution you gave didn’t work. But, I found a work around. I uninstalled the 64 bit anaconda dist. & re-installed the 32 bit and the problem was solved. But, the problem re-appears if I perform conda update.

Comment: Gld to know you found a solution for your problem!